# Compressed sensing - Why does my convex solver fail when I give it *more* samples?

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, cvx

I'm trying to implement compressed sensing of an image using the [cvx library](http://cvxr.com/cvx/download/) for MATLAB.
This is the same library used by Steve Brunton in his example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otr1YwNBWfc). My test image is [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna).

Here's my MATLAB script:

```html
close all; clear; clc

% read in an image
lenna = imread('lenna.png');
X = lenna(:, :, 2); % greem channel only
X = X(200:249, 100:149); % just a chunk
M = size(X, 1); N = size(X, 2);
x = vectorify(X);

figure, subplot(1, 3, 1), imshow(X), title(strcat("Original Image: ", num2str(M), " by ", num2str(N), " Pixels"))

% Sample randomly
K = 80; %number of random sampled pixels
c = randsample(numel(X), K); %locations of pixels as a list
y = x(c); %values
C = zeros(K, numel(X)); %C(c) = y;%(1:K);
Y = zeros(M, N); % there must be a more elegant way to do this...
for k=1:K
    C(k, c(k)) = y(k);
    Y2 = rectanglefy(C(k, :), M, N);
    Y=Y+Y2;
end
% Y=rectanglefy(C, M, N)
C = C>0; %convert C to a binary matrix
C = double(C); %cast
subplot(1, 3, 2), imshow(Y/255), title(strcat(num2str(K), ' Sampled Pixels'))


% Solve for sparse representation
psi = dftmtx(M*N); psi=real(psi);
Theta = C*psi; n = M*N;

Theta = double(Theta); y = double(y); %cast required
cvx_begin;
    variable s_L1(n)
    minimize( norm(s_L1, 1) );
    subject to
        Theta * s_L1 ==y; 
cvx_end

xr = psi*s_L1;
Xr = rectanglefy(xr, M, N);
subplot(1, 3, 3), imshow(Xr/255), title('Reconstructed Image')

function x = vectorify(X)
    x = reshape(X, [numel(X), 1]);
end

function X = rectanglefy(x, M, N)
    X = reshape(x, [M, N]);
end
```

When I run it with, say, K=80, it's able to reconstruct an image, although of course it's not very close to the real thing:
[image: Image reconstruction of 50x50 pixels, with 80 randomly sampled pixels.]

If I up the number of samples to 800, however - which I would expect would make the result closer - the solver tells me it's infeasible:
[image: Attempted image reconstruction with 800 randomly sampled pixels, and text from cvx solver in command window stating that solving is infeasible.]

In between, if I set K to 180 random samples, the solver yields "Failed," which is evidently a different result from "Infeasible":
[image: Attempted image reconstruction with 180 randomly sampled pixels, and text from cvx solver in command window stating that solving failed.]

I'm not sure if the problem is in my code or my (rather poor) understanding of convex optimization, but my question is: (a) why is this happening? and (b) what should I be doing differently to reconstruct this image?

Answer (score 1):

so I'm a bit of an ape without much experience on this stuff but I've tried to replicate your code and I got 2 tips as of now:

1: if you define the cvx part like this you'll get better results (which get better by increasing the sampling points:

```
epsilon=0.01;
%Using the cvx
cvx_begin;
    variable s_L1(n) complex
    minimize( norm(s_L1, 1) );
    subject to
        norm(y - Theta*s_L1,2) <= epsilon; 
cvx_end
```

2: You're turning a 2D image into a 1D vector, column by column, which means that your first element and 51st element have a very high correlation. I guess you'd be better off using a 2d fft, [like this](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html), but I'm not sure how one would implement that as of now. I'd be happy to share whatever I find if you're still interested in the topic. :)

hope that has helped.